# Android creating a JSON POST, how can i create this format using JSON objects/arrays

Tags: android, json

I am taking part in a group project for university, and i need to create a JSON POST request in the specified format. The part i am having trouble is, is the looping through an array of stored Objects, getting the values from the objects and creating JSON Objects with said values.

the format:

```
{
    "authorization": {
        "hash": "427339AC646C25EFFA6B624CE776FB4FEE99CEDA",
        "salt": "swordfish"
    },
    "walk": {
        "title": "Whitehall Wander",
        "shortDesc": "A short walk around Westminster",
        "longDesc": "A walk around London, viewing sights such as Downing Street, Trafalgar Square, and Scotland Yard",
        "locations": [
            {
                "latitude": 51.503396,
                "longitude": 0.127640,
                "timestamp": 0,
                "descriptions": [
                    "10 Downing Street"
                ],
                "images": [
                    "no10door",
                    "primeminister"
                ]
            },
            {
                "latitude": 51.506758,
                "longitude": 0.128692,
                "timestamp": 20,
                "descriptions": [
                    "Admiralty Arch"
                ],
                "images": [
                ]
            },
            {
                "latitude": 51.49861,
                "longitude": 0.13305,
                "timestamp": 60,
                "descriptions": [
                    "New Scotland Yard",
                    "Metropolitan Police HQ"
                ],
                "images": [
                    "revolvingsign"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

My question is how can i access the variables in my Objects so i do things like:

```
    try{
        JSONObject auth = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject walk = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray points = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject image = new JSONObject();

    auth.put("AUTH  TEST");

    for(int i = 0; i < pois.size(); i ++){


        points.put("name", pois.get(i).getName());

    }


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This throws an error:

```
 The method put(int, boolean) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

Is there a way to do this so it matches the above format?

The variables for each element in pois are:

```
name = String
description = String
latitude = Double
longitude = Double
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get it's cause an `JSONArray` cannot contain a set of key/value. It can either contain instances of `JSONObject` or `String`,`int`, etc...

Firstable, you should post more code cause `pois` is not declared anywhere. Also, If you're trying to get `JSONObject`s out of the big string you posted, you can pass that string to the constructor `JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonString)` and it creates it for you.

That being said, you can get out of `mainObj` the following:

```
JSONObject auth = mainObj.getJSONObject("authorization");
String hash = auth.getString("hash");
String salt = auth.getString("salt");

// To iterate over the location:
JSONArray locations = mainObj.getJSONObject("walk").getJSONArray("locations");

for(int i = 0; i < locations.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject locat = locations.getJSONObject(i);

   String latitude = locat.getString("latitude");
   // Etc...
}
```